# Expression of extreme surprise (possibly vulgar, but without being insulting)

Tags: translation, expression

Is there a formula or expression that I can use to express these English sentences?

> - **What on earth** did you just do?
> - **What the heck** did I just hear?
> - **What the hell** just happened?

or, in general,

> - What the …?

To make it clear, I want to express my extreme surprise, whether or not it involves the sexual connotation of the word "fuck".

Also I want to be able to express it in a way that is not insulting. Something that, said with the proper playful tone, can be said to friends or family.

Comment: Can you please provide some context? From what you've provided so far, I'd say your children did something bad and you're a little bit overreacting... ;) Especially the "... did I just hear" needs a bit more context (for me).

Comment: Quite a few people (including myself) use the English expression even in German, at least when cursing to themselves.

Comment: "...these classical sentences of the English language".  How time flies: we had a rather more restricted notion of "classical"  when I started learning English :-)

Comment: If you want something that is NOT offensive then why ask for "What the fuck" ? The title as it is has little to do with the answer you accepted. I edited it.

Comment: Tja, jetzt ist alles plötzlich *fuckfree*, also *ad usum delfini*, damit sind natürlich auch einige Antworten sinnlos geworden. Die Frage war ja nicht, wie man im Nonnenkloster flucht, ohne daß die Äbtissin beleidigt ist. Leider ist das "una cazzata"

Comment: In my way of seeing it, just because it contains the word "fuck", does not make it offensive. I am against this edit, as now all the answers given seem unappropiate.

Comment: Oh nein, jetzt soll es auch noch *höflich* sein. Also etwas, das man auch in der Gegenwart des Papstes sagen kann. Bitte, das ist jetzt echte Scheiße!

Comment: O Gott, was soll die Prüderie, @Emanuel? Durch Deine Edit hast Du die ganze Frage völlig abgedreht. Es gibt Flüche im Englischen und Deutschen und es ging um den Zusammenhang.  Jetzt geht es darum, wie man in Gegenwart eines Zweijährigen Überraschung ausrückt. Das ist was anderes!

Comment: Ich musste erst die Edithistorie und die Kommentare anschauen, bevor ich wusste, worum es geht. Momentan fragt der Titel nach höflichen Ausdrücken und die Frage beantwortet nicht richtig, welchen Grad an Höflichkeit. "Was zum Kuckuck/Geier" kann man in einem Verwandtentreffen benutzen, aber vermutlich nicht in Gegenwart des Papstes. Ich bin für einen Titel der Art "Idiomatic expressions of extreme surprise", das sollte die Antworten on-topic machen.

Comment: @Dbugger... I have met plenty native English speakers who have a different opinion and who find it very offensive even as a statement of surprise. Feel free to roll back, it's your question, but I stand by my statement that asking for "fuck" in the title and then saying it shouldn't be offensive makes no sense.

Comment: Of course some people might find it offensive. But i say it in a daily basis. And people who know me know what i mean, and they can laugh it off. That is what i was going for. (At this point of the discussion, i don't dare modify the question further)

Comment: @Karl Warum 3 Kommentare? Im ersten hast du doch alles gesagt. Auf mein Argument bist du leider nicht eingegangen. Vielleicht war es nicht klar genug: der Titel der Frage suggeriert, dass es darum geht "What the fuck" zu übersetzen. Darum geht es aber offenbar nicht, da es OP nicht ums "fuck" an sich geht und die Antwort zudem nicht anstössig sein soll. Ich sehe daher keinen Grund, nicht einfach genau das zu fragen... "Way to express extreme surprise". Das "polite" könnte wohl sicher raus.

Comment: @Karl... und von wegen Nonnenkloster und so... guck dir doch mal bitte die Antwort an, die akzeptiert wurde. Das sieht nicht nach Strasse aus sondern eher nach konservativem  Mittelstandsfluchen. ich finde sie passt jetzt besser, als sie zu "What the fuck" gepasst hat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

German swearing only rarely is associated with sexuality, hence a literal counterpart does not exist. Most swearwords are closely related with religious themes. This is also the case in the examples give in the question [as was already pointed out](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/18798/23):

> **Um Himmels willen**, was hast du gemacht?
>   Was, **in Gottes Namen**, habe ich da soeben gehört?
>   **Um Gottes willen**, was ist passiert?

An example that comes close to the English in sound, and is widely accepted as not being too rude is:

> Was **zum Kuckuck** hast Du da gemacht?
>   Was **zum Kuckuck** ist da los?
>   **Zum Kuckuck** mit dir!

Here the name **[Kuckuck](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Kuckuck)** is a placeholder for the devil.

Comment: Habe auch schon "zum Geier" gehört

Comment: Religiöse Themen erscheinen beim Fluchen im Deutschen eher bei Pietisten, nicht im normalen Sprachgebrauch.

Answer (score 13):

According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/english-german/What+the+fuck+++WTF.html)

> Was zum Teufel ...
>
> Was verdammt ...
>
> Was zur Hölle ...

I bet there are some even "umgangssprachlicher".

Comment: Of all these, which would you think is the least aggressive, that could even be used jokingly?

Comment: Better wait for a native speaker on this one. To me, neither "was zum Teufel" nor "was zur Hölle" seem especially rude or vulgar, but I can't really say for sure.

Comment: They are not what you'd say when you visit the Bundespräsident, but they are not terribly rude or vulgar either.

Comment: Takkat’s answers are considerably less aggressive. I guess talking about heaven is preferred to talking about hell or damnation.

Answer (score 3):

Mein Vorschlag:

*Was hast Du denn für einen Scheiß gemacht, verdammt nochmal?*

*Was ist das den für eine gottverdammte Scheiße, die da eben passiert ist?*

Wie @Takkat gesagt hat, deutsche Flüche haben selten einen sexuellen Inhalt, aber
im Gegensatz zu ihm würde ich sagen, daß sie eher einen analfixierten Inhalt haben als religiösen. Also allgemein (zur Frage passen die beiden ersten):

Scheiße, Scheißdreck, Arschloch, kannst mich am Arsch lecken, usw.

Seine Vorschläge halte ich für ein bißchen zu harmlos.

EDIT:
 Die Antwort bezieht sich auf die ursprüngliche Frage, die englische Ausdrücke mit *what the f+ck* übersetzt haben wollte. Zur jetzigen paßt sie daher nich mehr,

Comment: Ad hominem Kritik (auch ohne Namen zu nennen) hat keinen Platz in Antworten. Genauso wenig wie Kritik an Edits, Kommentaren u.Ä. Für so etwas existieren [meta] und [chat]. Danke!

Comment: Es geht hier nicht um Fluchen, es geht um Verwunderung; ohne den Kontext zu kennen, kann  die Überaschung negativ als auch positiv sein. "Scheiß" passt hier mit 50% Chance nicht.

Comment: @Robert Da die ursprüngliche Frage mehrmals abgeändert wurde, ist es jetzt müßig zu spekulieren, ob meine Antwort zur jetzigen paßt. Vogel612 hat mein Edit, daß es sich auf die ursprüngliche Frage bezieht, *ungefragt gelöscht*.

Comment: @Vogel612 Da ich nie ad hominem Argumente (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_hominem) hier gebraucht habe, bleibt mir der Sinn Deines Kommentars verborgen. Eventuell ist Dir der Begriff nicht ganz klar. Durch Dein Edit ist jetzt meine Antwort total unverständlich geworden. Siehe Roberts Kommentar eben.

Comment: @Karl "Die totale Änderung von jemand anders" enthält also keine reductio ad hitlerum?? Dann habe ich da wohl den Kontext fehlgedeutet. Im übrigen finde ich die Antwort auch ohne diese Notiz nicht schlecht

Comment: Vogel612 Oh Gottchen, wieso mußt Du denn  gleich mit dem Adolf kommen (*reductio ad hitlerum*)? Kritik wird gleich mit dem Nazi-Vergleich beantwortet. Bitte lies doch den Begriff *ad hominem Argument* nochmal nach, Du redest da von was völlig anderem.

Comment: @Karl korrekt. Zu meiner Verteidigung sei gesagt, ich hatte die ganze Nacht nicht geschlafen... Was ich meinte ist ein "direkter Angriff auf eine Person" nicht eine ad hominem Argumentation. Interessanterweise kann das auch durch den lat. Begriff ausgedrückt werden...

Answer (score 1):

Karoshis Liste umfasst m.E. die gebräuchlichsten Flüche in dieser Form. Am nähsten dran an WTF könnte aber

> Was, verfickt, ...

sein, aber sehr gebräuchlich ist es nicht. Wenn man es aber gestisch/mimisch oder durch die Betonung nicht vergeigt kann es als Fluch durchgehen.

Comment: @Dbugger IIRC the official consensus on meta was that answers jn a different language than the question were not optimal, but definitely not wrong. I may be remembering wrongly though and strongly suggest asking on [meta] if you want to discuss this further

Comment: Ich habe im deutschen Internet (aber noch nie offline) die Eindeutschung "was zum Fick" gelesen und fand das recht passend, weil es parallel zum deutschen Ausruf "was zum/zur Kuckuck/Hölle/Geier/..." gebildet wird. Richtig verstehen werden es aber vermutlich nur Menschen, die das englische WTF auch kennen, vermute ich.

Comment: Die englischen Beispiele haben den negativen Touch nicht; es geht hier nicht um Fluchen. Wenn einem der Barkeeper ein Bier ausgibt, kann man seinen Kumpel verwundert angucken und sagen "what the fuck just happened?", aber auf deutsch wird da keiner "verfickt" sagen.

Comment: @Robert: Mit einem entspannten Tonfall und einem Lachen in der Stimme wird ein "Was verfickt" sowenig einen negativen Touch haben wie "Was zum Henker". Der erste Tonfall der Dir zu einem Satz einfällt ist nicht notwenig der einzig mögliche.

Answer (score 1):

Mehr in Richtung "What/Why on earth..." geht "Was/Warum, **um alles in der Welt**...".

Answer (score 0):

Simple alternatives would be

> WAS ist passiert!?

or

> Bitte WAS hast du gemacht!?